# Rings and Categories of Modules by Anderson-Fuller: Exercise 2.2.2

Tags: ring-theory, modules

The following is Exercise 2.2.2 from Anderson & Fuller's book *Rings and Categories of Modules*:

> Let $_\mathbb{C}V$ be a non-zero complex vector space. The abelian group $V$ becomes a left $\mathbb{C}$-vector space$_\mathbb{C}\overline V$ with the scalar multiplication $(\alpha,x)\mapsto \overline\alpha x$. Prove that neither of these $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces $_\mathbb{C}V$ and $_\mathbb{C}\overline V$ is a subspace of each other and that these two $\mathbb{C}$-scalar multiplications do not form a $(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$-bimodule.

The authors define a submodule of a (left) $R$-module $M$ as an abelian subgroup of $M$ closed under scalar multiplication by $R$. I'm not really sure what the exercise is asking, since both $V$ and $\overline V$ are the same when looked as sets, and therefore if one is closed under one multiplication, then both are. Some people at the webchat suggested that the authors meant that one should prove that those module structures were incompatible with each other, which makes sense, but I can't see how that connects with the definition that is given in the text.

Comment: One should also point that, at least when $V$ is finite-dimensional, then both $V$ and $\overline V$ have the same dimension as $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces and hence are isomorphic (though the identity is not an isomorphism).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that there is no $\mathbb{C}$-linear isomorphism between $_\mathbb{C}V$ and $_\mathbb{C}\overline{V}$. One way to view a subspace is: if $V$ is a vector space (over any field $k$), and $W \subseteq V$ is any subset of $V$, then $W$ is a subspace of $V$ iff $W$ has the structure of a $k$-vector space, and the inclusion map $W \hookrightarrow V$ (which is the identity on sets) is $k$-linear. This implies $W$ is an additive subgroup of $V$, and the scalar multiplications agree, for instance.

As a (perhaps silly) example, consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as a 1-dimensional vector space over itself. Then $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is a subset, which has an abstract structure of a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space (as does any countable set, by placing it in bijection with $\mathbb{Q}$, and acting via this bijection). But $\mathbb{N}$ is certainly **not** considered a subspace of $\mathbb{Q}$, and the inclusion $\mathbb{N} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is not $\mathbb{Q}$-linear.

Returning to your question, it is true that $_\mathbb{C}\overline{V}$ is a subset of $_\mathbb{C}V$,
so it is a subspace iff the inclusion $j : {}_\mathbb{C}\overline{V} \hookrightarrow {}_\mathbb{C}V$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear. But it is not: for any nonzero $v \in _\mathbb{C}\overline{V}$, $j(i \cdot v) = j(iv) = iv$, but $i \cdot j(v) = \overline{i}j(v) = -iv$.

For the last part about bimodules, it's not completely clear what is meant: for a bimodule structure you need a left and a right action, whereas both actions seem to be defined on the left. The candidate bimodule is not explicitly mentioned either, i.e. which of $_\mathbb{C}V$ or $_\mathbb{C}\overline{V}$ is not a bimodule.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{C}$ is commutative, any left action can be also seen as a right action.

Comment: @egreg: True, but *which* left action is to be viewed as a right action should still be specified

Comment: The exercise says that *no* bimodule structure can be given, so it's immaterial which one is used as right action.

Comment: Ah, well if you take that viewpoint, then yes, it does make sense. The exact wording in the problem just seemed confusing to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd say the spaces are indeed isomorphic (because both have the same dimension), but what happens is that the inclusion map is not $\mathbb{C}$-linear. While I agree that this solves the first part, I'm still not sure about the part about the bimodule structure.